# how to suffice a Zero based on the count of values in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a column year as below

```
Year
202
2021
2022
202
2019
```

I need to add "0" for all the column values which has "202"

how can I do it

Expected Output

```
 Year
 2020
 2021
 2022
 2020
 2019
```

Code so far:

```
df['Year_1'] = df['Year'].str.len()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can multiple values by `10` for values less like `1000`:

```
df.loc[df.Year.lt(1000), 'Year'] *= 10
print (df)
   Year
0  2020
1  2021
2  2022
3  2020
4  2019
```

If working with strings add `0` if strings has lengths `3`:

```
df.Year = df.Year.astype(str)

df.loc[df['Year'].str.len().eq(3), 'Year'] += '0'
print (df)
   Year
0  2020
1  2021
2  2022
3  2020
4  2019
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to [`ljust`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.ljust.html):

```
df['Year'] = df['Year'].str.ljust(4, '0')
```

Output:

```
   Year
0  2020
1  2021
2  2022
3  2020
4  2019
```